# “Tel” as a pejorative indefinite adjective

Tags: adjectifs-indefinis

I recall seeing somewhere once that “tel” could be used pejoratively in the following sense, for example:

> -*Il est rentré chez lui hier soir avec telle fille.*
>
> -He went home last night with some girl.

Is this correct? I remember reading that this usage is possible, but I can’t find where I read that.

I know it can be used an as indefinite adjective, but I’m curious if this sense carries the same negative meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe was it about the adjective phrase ***tel ou tel*** :

> Il est rentré chez lui hier soir avec telle ou telle fille.

In that case, *telle ou telle fille* is not explicitly pejorative but means it doesn't matter which girl it was precisely.

Comment: That’s it! I was close. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No, "tel" isn't pejorative. But it can be used to emphasize something, good or bad. For example :

> Je me rappelle de cet achat, c'était une telle arnaque !
>
> I remember that purchase, it was such a scam !

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I could convey my original idea in French then? The idea that he went home with “some girl” (who was apparently unimportant to him).

Comment: Mmmh no I don't see a quick way to formulate that. Context would make it clear, like : "Il est encore rentré avec une fille hier soir" - "encore" would highlight a repetitive pattern, thus the unimportance of the girl.

Comment: This works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Pour garder le sens péjoratif, on pourrait écrire :

> -Il est rentré chez lui hier soir avec une fille quelconque.

Cf le sens 3. de quelconque [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelconque).

Comment: J’ai compris. Donc il y a une différence alors entre « quelconque » et « quiconque » en fonction de ce contexte ? Quelconque signifie « any » tandis que quiconque signifie « anyone » , non ?

Comment: @tssmith2425 Oui. Attention cependant, "any" pourrait se traduire d'une autre façon (ça pourraît être "[n'importe quel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%E2%80%99importe_quel)" ou encore "[n'importe lequel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%E2%80%99importe_lequel)"). Et réciproquement, "quiconque" pourrait aussi être "[n'importe qui](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%E2%80%99importe_qui)". Cela dépend du contexte.

Comment: Oui. On pourrait dire "il est rentré chez lui hier soir avec n’importe quelle femme ?

Comment: @tssmith2425 Non. C'est effectivement à rapprocher de l'idée qu'il s'agit de quelqu'un de commun, banal (donc un peu « n'importe quelle femme »), mais cette tournure « une fille quelconque » (souvent appuyée : « une fille très quelconque ») a un sens péjoratif pour la fille, qui est supposée n'avoir aucun attrait, rien qui la fasse sortir du lot, sans intérêt.